# MySQL: Select and return articles where date between two weeks

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to display most recent visited articles in top of my page, but my query fail even if I put in phpmyadmin.

Here is my query, hope someone can find a solution:

```
SELECT `slug`,`title`,`image` FROM  `article` WHERE DATE(`date`) = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 16 DAY) ORDER BY  `article`.`view_count` DESC LIMIT 0 , 5
```

I'll select slug, title and image between 2 week ordered by view count, but the query return 0 elements.

Data format in the table is YYYY-MM-DD.

Thanks to all

Comment: if you don't add PHP in your snippet, you shouldn't put `php` as a tag...

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: No. Ask a better question.

Comment: I got no errors, the query return 0 elements, I think is cause the data is in an incorrect format (YYYY-MM-DD) it's possible? How can I set the data format in query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get a date in the future, and you're trying to find articles on that exact date:

```
select DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 16 DAY);
+--------------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 16 DAY) |
+--------------------------------------+
| 2016-08-12                           |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Use DATE_SUB to look in the past, and `>=` to get that date and forward:

```
DATE(`date`) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 16 DAY)
```